# QML osm MapItemView MapPolyline opacity

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, openstreetmap

I have `QQuickWidget` and QML in it

```
Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    objectName: "mapPlugin"
    name: "osm"

    ...
}

Map {
    id: map
    objectName: "map"
    ....

    MapItemView {
        id: mapItemPath
        model: mapProxyModel

        delegate: MapPolyline {
            path: pathRole

            line.color: "red"
            line.width: 10
            // opacity: 0.5
       }
       opacity: 0.5
}
```

actually opacity not working. Why that could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make opacity work on the `MapPolyLine` you either should set `opacity` or use [Qt.rgba()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#rgba-method) to create a color with an alpha value appropriate to use your opacity you want to get.

```
Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
}

Map {
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(-27, 153.0)
    zoomLevel: 8

    MapPolyline {
        line.width: 10
        line.color: Qt.rgba(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
        //opacity: 0.5
        path: [
            { latitude: -27, longitude: 153.0 },
            { latitude: -27, longitude: 154.1 },
            { latitude: -28, longitude: 153.5 },
            { latitude: -29, longitude: 153.5 }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]